# Posting photo to Facebook page as admin using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I know there are plenty of other similar requests on here for this - but none of them offer a solution that I have been able to find.  First please don't direct me to a PHP answer - I need to use the JavaScript SDK for this implementation and I am looking to solve it with JavaScript.

I am trying to post a photo to a Facebook page that the logged in user is an admin for.  I am getting what I believe to be the page access_token but it still posts the photo as the user to the page rather then as the page admin like this:

[image]

Instead of like this:

[image]

I am fairly certain I am using the page access_token with correct permissions as you can see here from Facebook's Access Token Debugger:
[image]

So here is my code:

```
<script>
  var current_login_status = "start";
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',  // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : true,         // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true          // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated the app,
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        PostToFB(uid, accessToken);
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated the app
        FB.login(function(response) {
            current_login_status=response.status;
            if (response.authResponse) {
                 window.location.reload(true);
               } else {
                 alert('User did not fully authorize.');
               }
        }, {scope: 'publish_stream,manage_pages'});
      } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.;           
        FB.login(function(response) {
            current_login_status=response.status;
            if (response.authResponse) {
                 window.location.reload(true);
               } else {
                 alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
               }
        }, {scope: 'publish_stream,manage_pages'});
      }
    });
  };

  function PostToFB(uid, accessToken) {
    FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT page_id, name, page_url FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid='+ uid+')'
        },
        function(data) {
            // Do something with the response
            var page_id = data[0].page_id;
            var page_accessToken = ''
            FB.api(
                '/'+uid+'/accounts',
                function(returnData) {                  
                    page_accessToken = returnData.data[0].access_token;
                }
            );
            FB.api(
                '/'+page_id+'/photos',
                'POST',
                {
                    'access_token': page_accessToken,
                    'message': 'Beer Description',
                    'url': "IMAGE_URL"
                },
                function (response) {
                  if (response && !response.error) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    console.log(response);
                  } else {
                    console.log(response);
                  }
                }
            );              

        }
    );                
  };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));    
</script>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB.api works asynchronous, so your third FB.api call does not have any value set in `page_accessToken` (and so the user access token is used).

Put your third FB.api call into the callback handler of the second one – same way as you did with the second call in the callback of the first one.